# UDP recvfrom warning with gcc compiler

Tags: c, sockets, udp, gcc-warning, recvfrom

I am receiving the following `warning` when compiling my `client - server UDP socket` simulation:

> warning: passing 'int *' to parameter of type 'socklen_t *' (aka
>   'unsigned int *') 
>       converts between pointers to integer types with different sign [-Wpointer-sign]

This is the concerned code:

```
#define BUFLEN 2048
struct sockaddr_in myaddr, remaddr;
int fd, recvlen, slen=sizeof(remaddr);
...
char response[BUFLEN];
recvlen = recvfrom(fd, response, BUFLEN - 1, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&remaddr, &slen);
```

I have been referencing a tutorial from Rutgers university. I have a fair idea as to why this warning is occuring (it wants me to use `socklen_t *`), but I wanted to ask the SO community.

1. Why is this warning occuring?
2. How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is this warning occuring?

The warning is occurring because `socklen_t` is an unsigned type, and `int` is a signed type (as the diagnostic says).  In principle, therefore, the pointed-to value may be interpreted differently by `recvfrom()` than it is by the caller.  In practice, such a difference won't happen with GCC-compiled code as long as only correct values of the length of the address `struct` are used, but GCC can't check that at compile time.

> How can I get rid of it?

Pass an argument of the correct type.

Answer (score 1):

> it wants me to use `socklen_t *`

Correct.

> Why is this warning occuring?

Because you aren't using `socklen_t`.

> How can I get rid of it?

Declare `slen` as `socklen_t`.